# ASP:GridView Pass Row to HTML Div

Tags: gridview, aspxgridview

The below code is an example I have been working on to demo how you can create popups from an `asp:gridview`.

It works fine but since the `<DIV>` is set on page load I am always getting the first instance of the `gridview`.

I am trying to figure out how to get the selected value in the DIV.  I'm assuming I need to either pass the value to the DIV somehow but trying to accomplish this without code behind.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" id="GridView1"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderColor="White" GridLines="None" HorizontalAlign="Left">
<Columns>
    <asp:templatefield HeaderText="Metrics:" SortExpression="Column Name">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("[Column Name]") %>' id="Label1" ToolTip="Click to see detail.">
            </asp:Label>
            </a>
        <div id="light" class="white_content">
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("[ToolTip]") %>' id="Label2" ToolTip="Click to see detail.">
            </asp:Label>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">
                <br>
                <br>
                Exit</br></br></a></div>
            <div id="fade" class="black_overlay">
        </div>

        </ItemTemplate>
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Font-Bold="True" Font-Underline="True" />
    </asp:templatefield>
</Columns>
```

Comment: Tim, this isn't classic ASP!  Can you lose the tag please?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I worked on WebForms projects, but probably the IDs are confusing the grid, since you are setting up the ID directly in the template.

My suggestion is that you use a function to dynamically set the ID or use a Grid event handler to pick the ID during the data binding process. This way you will be able to define the correct ID for the javascript.

There might be also another elegant solution by using a CSS class to select the DIV.

Let me know if this helps.

Thanks!
Rafael